# searching session - secure shell extension to chrome

Tags: shell, google-chrome, search, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste

Using OSX Mavericks,13 inch 2011 MBA. I have moved all my development into the chrome secure shell - consistent shortcuts, easy navigation.

Trying to search within a secure shell session - from previous commands and output I can't do it. Couldn't find documentation or use the obvious candidates - `Cmd + f`, `Cmd  + s`.

I don't want to use `Ctrl + r` to search previous commands, as I need a more powerful search ability.

Alternatively, I'm thinking of saving all terminal input and output to a file and searching that with grep, with a suitable alias.

Also, when I copy/paste from one secure-shell to another with emacs( shared-buffers enabled with OS and emacs in secure-shell) it gets messed up and won't parse. However, if I paste into another WebApp such as google keep or gmail, the text gets copied fine.

Comment: I need to rewrite this. No response on stackoverflow!!! Appreciate insight on what parts are unclear.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Find-in-page" feature in Secure Shell at the moment.  The feature request is here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=209178

As a workaround, you can select everything in the terminal, copy it to the clipboard, and then open a new tab pointed to the URL: 'data:text/html,<textarea style="height:100%;width:100%">', paste into that textarea, and then use the standard `Cmd - f` to find-in-page.

Or, if you just want to search the output of a command, you can use something like `cat /var/log/messages | grep foo`.

I don't know what you mean by "messed up and won't parse", maybe a screenshot or description of exactly how you're copy/pasting, or elaboration on "messed up" would help.